# Filtering a raster asset using list of values in Google Earth Engine

Tags: filter, google-earth-engine

I am trying to filter a raster asset that uses numeric values to define land uses. My initial purpose is to use a list of values to filter all the areas corresponding to bushes (codes 410, 420 and 430).

With the updateMask method this can be easily done with the following code:

```js
var landuse = ee.Image('users/xxx/cover2014');
var masked = landuse.updateMask(landuse.eq(410).or(landuse.eq(420)).or(landuse.eq(430)));
```

My problem relies on the fact that I want to use another land uses through a checkbox, so I was thinking in a code like this (I did not include the code used for panel and checkbox):

```js
var forest = ee.List([211, 212, 221, 222, 231, 232, 241, 251]);
var bush = ee.List([410, 420, 430, 440, 450]);

var filterList = forest.cat(bush);

var landuse = ee.Image('users/xxx/cover2014');
var masked = landuse.updateMask(landuse.eq(filterList));

Map.addLayer(masked);
```

Sadly, the updateMask method gives an error because I am using a list instead of a image. I have also tried with the operator 'in', 'inList', without success.

Is there any way to use values contained in a list to update the mask or filtering a raster asset?

EDIT:

The final code, using the provided solution is:

```js
var forest = ee.List([211, 212, 221, 222, 231, 232, 241, 251]);
var bush = ee.List([410, 420, 430, 440, 450]);

var filterList = forest.cat(bush);

var landuse = ee.Image('users/xxx/cover2014');

var masked = landuse.updateMask(landuse.eq(ee.Image.constant(filterList)).reduce(ee.Reducer.anyNonZero()));

Map.addLayer(masked);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ee.Image.eq() actually returns a multiband image here. Try the following to fix it:

```js
var masked = landuse.updateMask(landuse.eq(filterList).reduce(ee.Reducer.anyNonZero()))
```

The filterList may need to be wrapped with an image to make sure it can be used in ee.Image.eq():

```js
filterList = ee.Image.constant(filterList)
```

Comment: The code does not work, it gives me the following error: Layer 1: Layer error: Image.eq, argument 'image2': Invalid type. Expected: Image<unknown bands>. Actual: List<Long>.

Comment: Try to convert your filterList from a list of longs to an image, like this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d3d7adf81904d7803a5a153460068faa

Comment: As you mentioned in your comment edition, the ee.Image.constant() command did the trick. This piece of code, included in your link, was the solution: var masked = landuse.updateMask(landuse.eq(ee.Image.constant(filterList)).reduce(ee.Reducer.anyNonZero()))